# Django Tests(TestCase), проблемы с fixtures, c reverse

Tags: python, django, reverse

В тесты добавляю Fixtures, и при запуске тестов выдает ошибку:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Пытался кодировать в другие форматы - ничего не меняется.

Вторая проблема: использую `reverse`, передавая `name='url'` и `kwargs` для передачи `id`, так как url выглядит так:

```
path('category/<int:category_id>/', category_recipes, name='category_recipes')
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Код теста выглядит так:

```
class RecipesViewTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['categories.json', 'recipes.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.recipes = RecipesModel.objects.all()

    def test_list_with_category(self):
        categories = CategoriesModel.objects.first()
        path = reverse('category', kwargs={'category_id': categories.id})
        response = self.client.get(path)

        self.assertEqual(
            list(response.context_data['category']),
            list(self.recipes.filter(category_id=categories.id))
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Первая проблема связана с кодировкой данных в файле fixtures. Скорее всего они были сохранены в другой кодировке.

Потом ошибка возникает потому, что в reverse вы указываете name='url', в то время как имя URL-шаблона 'category_recipes'.

`path = reverse('category_recipes', kwargs={'category_id': categories.id})`
Вроде так, особо не проверял

Comment: После смены на имя url, ошибка осталась таже, а fixtures я просто дампил и в полях модели там были не понятные символы, я погуглил и нашел что у винды проблемы с этим и надо в настройках винды, включить кодировку utf-8, потом передампил и буквы стали нормальные но появилась данная ошибка.